# Retrieve an image of the fax sent using RFCOMAPILib (RIGHTFAX)

Tags: fax, rightfax

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to retrieve a copy of the fax that was sent using the RFCOMAPILib?

I am able to send faxes easily, but a new requirement has come up that the fax that was sent be viewable to the users. Currently I log the handle of the fax object and use that to retrieve status updates.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how to do so:

```
// add using statements

using RFCOMAPILib;

// Do some stuff here if needed...


// initialize your fax server api
faxAPI = new RFCOMAPILib.FaxServer();

// you can set this in the .config files if need be.
faxAPI.ServerName = "[YourFaxServerHere]";
faxAPI.Protocol = RFCOMAPILib.CommunicationProtocolType.cpSecTCPIP;

// since i am working with multiple users, i iterated through the users and retrieved their
// respective passwords (encrypted of course) but you can insert the string value here or
// set it in the .config file.
faxAPI.AuthorizationUserID = "[UserNameYouAreRetrievingImageFor]";
faxAPI.AuthorizationUserPassword = "[UserPassword]";
faxAPI.UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.False;

// Do some stuff here if needed...


// initialize fax object
RFCOMAPILib.Fax rfFax = (RFCOMAPILib.Fax)faxAPI.get_Fax([FaxHandleAsIntValueHere])
```

Hope this works for you!